# Stopping a thread without loop (a function that takes a long time)

Tags: python, multithreading, download

I'm writing a program that at 3AM, it reads everything from a file and downloads the files from the links one by one, and stops doing so (pauses the download) if it's 7AM

But my problem is If I use `os.system("wget name")` I won't be able to stop it, I can't put a flag in a while loop to check it because `os.system()` won't finish until the download is complete. I can't think of any other way.
My net is unstable so I assume I have to use `wget`, I heard of `urllib` but I'm not sure if it will work with my unstable connection!

I'm planning on running this on ArchLinux on my raspberry Pi

Comment: use `handle = subprocess.Popen(['wget', 'name'])` instead. The `handle` has a function called `.poll()` to check status and `.terminate()` to terminate the process. There's also a `send_signal(SIGNAL)` but all of this is dangerous if not done correctly.

Comment: And then the killed subprocess still runs in the background? Guess he needs something like a process group described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true

Comment: Thanks a lot! that will work I guess, It's too late now I will write the code tomarrow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a subprocess you want to stop at 7 AM. `Popen.wait` has a timeout so all you have to do is figure out the timeout and use it.

```
import subprocess
import datetime
import time

now = datetime.datetime.now()
stopat = now.replace(hour=7, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
delta = stopat.timestamp() - now.timestamp()
if delta > 0:
    proc = subprocess.Popen("wget name", shell=True)
    try:
        proc.wait(delta)
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        proc.terminate()
        try:
            proc.wait(2)
        except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
            proc.kill()
```